# Terraform -Autoscaling -mulltiple security groups

Tags: autoscaling

I would like to launch a single instance in each AZ(us-east-1a,us-east-1b).

I need to attach security Groups A,B,C to  instance launching in subnet us-east-1a,
I need to attach security Groups D,E,F to  instance launching in subnet us-east-1b, using launch configuration and autoscaling group in AWS via terraform.

please advise your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to script that as part of your userdata.  An ASG will attach the same security group to all instances.  Why do you want different ones in different subnets?  Shouldn't all the instances in the ASG need the same access as all the others?

I'd also recommend using security group name/ID references instead of specific subnet ranges when possible